# Joining a record table with a mapping table on negative relationships

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Say I have a two tables `record` and `tag`, in which `record` contains a lot of detailed information, and `tag` simply contains a positive relationship between records and a tag, i.e.

Table `tag` contains following columns:

```
tag        ENUM 'SomeTagA','SomeTagB','SomeTagC' NOT NULL
record_id  INT NOT NULL
```

Combination (`tag`, `record_id`) is unique.

Now, I can easily query on positive relationships using (INNER) JOIN:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM record AS r
JOIN tag AS t1 ON t1.record_id = r.id AND t1.tag = "SomeTagA"
JOIN tag AS t2 ON t2.record_id = r.id AND t2.tag = "SomeTagB"
```

However, what if I want to negate on the third tag. Like, select all records that have tag A and tag B, but not tag C. The only solution I can come up with is:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM record AS r
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tag WHERE tag = "SomeTagA" and record_id = r.id) = 1
  AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tag WHERE tag = "SomeTagB" and record_id = r.id) = 1
  AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tag WHERE tag = "SomeTagC" and record_id = r.id) = 0
```

But I can imagine that being a somewhat slow solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation to satisfy your criteria

```
SELECT r.col1, r.col2
FROM record AS r
JOIN tag AS t ON t.record_id = r.id
GROUP BY r.col1, r.col2
HAVING SUM(t.tag = 'SomeTagA') > 1
AND SUM(t.tag = 'SomeTagB') > 1
AND SUM(t.tag = 'SomeTagC') = 0
```

`SUM(t.tag = 'SomeTagA')`  can be represented as `SUM(CASE WHEN t.tag = 'SomeTagA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`, In mysql using sum with some expression like sum(a = b) will result in a boolean and you will get a count based on your expression

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about the HAVING syntax, that is brilliant.